# How to detect if the main app is in the foreground in the NotificationServiceExtension?

Tags: ios, swift

My app allows APNS notifications to come in whether the app is backgrounded or foregrounded, e.g.:

```swift
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UserNotificationCenterProtocol, willPresent notification: NotificationProtocol, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
}
```

However, within the extension itself it seems I can't determine if the app is currently foregrounded or backgrounded. Trying to use UIApplication.shared results in an error:

```swift
let application = UIApplication.shared
```

The error:

> 'shared' is unavailable in application extensions for iOS: Use view controller based solutions where appropriate instead.

**Is there another way to determine the apps current state in the Notification Service Extension?**  I see there are some lifecycle methods specific to extensions, such as NSExtensionHostWillEnterForeground, but I don't know how to subscribe to those notifications ([the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotification/name/1616748-nsextensionhostwillenterforegrou) is sparse).

Comment: Your code seems to be good. It is UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .active. Did you import UIKIt ?

Comment: The problem is extensions can't used UIApplication.shared. Apparently apple doesn't want extensions to know the state of the main app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, this isn't possible as of right now.

My guess is that Apple doesn't want these extensions to depend on the state of the main app.

Comment: I guess you meant "Apple doesnt" in this case.